# Can anyone offer an opinion on handlersocket vs memcached performance in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, innodb, nosql, mysql-5.6, memcached

I must say I was a little mis(un)-informed about the MySQL `Memcached` plugin which offers the same `NoSQL` like access to `InnoDB` tables as `HandlerSocket`, I had only had experience with entirely standalone memcached servers in cacheing scenarios.

We're using HandlerSocket quite heavily, as it provided a massive increase in IO, and from the original papers on the subject (at the time), it was actually faster than traditional memcached access, thus why we pursued it.

However in learning that the new memcache plugin serves the same purpose now, I went searching for benchmarks, comparisons, or even cock-eyed opinion, but wasn't able to find any specifically addressing both.

I'd like to know if anyone has had experience with both, switched to/from either and what their experiences were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone make this bench:
http://mimdl.tumblr.com/post/115308901909/benchmarking-handlersocket-mysql-innodb-memcached

- Get Operation with HandlerSocket was completed in 1.20499610901 Sec, i.e; making 8,299 QPS (Queries per second)
- Get Operation with InnoDB Memcached Plugin was completed in .93115 seconds i.e; making 10,739 QPS
- Select Query for MySQL took 333.834 seconds which is considerably low

But there is 10000 small select, not one big.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using InnoDB memcached over Handlersocket.  The advantage of InnoDB memcached is that:

- It uses a standard memcached protocol, with drivers available for many programming languages.
- It does not automatically allow access to all tables in your database, but instead tables 'opt-in' via a mapping containers table.
- It has a stated [support policy](http://www.mysql.com/support/) of 8 years.  MySQL 5.6/5.7 support already exists for InnoDB memcached, and these version upgrades are required to unlock many of the scalability enhancements.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Morgan.  I'm hoping you can expand with more experience on your answer.  My first reaction is, the first point doesn't matter, it's not like we're choosing prior to using either, like I said we're already heavily invested in `handlersocket`, it will be a LOT of work to move over but that's not to say that we wouldn't if it's in our best interest.  The only numbers I've seen were early on but `handlersocket` still left `memcache` in the dust, has that changed now that it's baked in so to speak?

Comment: The second point is more interesting but again not sure it matters all that much since we're in an EC2 Virtual Private Cloud, and the DB is inaccessible to anything but our app servers.

Comment: On performance: I don't have direct comparison numbers, but in MySQL 5.7 InnoDB memcached can achieve 1.1 million requests/second. See: http://dimitrik.free.fr/blog/archives/2013/11/mysql-performance-over-1m-qps-with-innodb-memcached-plugin-in-mysql-57.html

Comment: On importance of API/protocol: if does simplify development environments as well.  Maybe not enough to justify migrating, but wins in an apples to apples comparison.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, the post from Dimitri was quite impressive, good to know that this is where the attention is being paid, although, you'll notice at the end of the article, he mentions bypassing the Memcache API altogether and accessing the InnoDB API which is what handlersocket does, and how much more impressive that *could* be...  :)

Comment: WRT the API/Protocol, we've already abstracted that and written the interpreters, so we've already simplified devops.  We'd just need to write a new interpreter to work under our abstraction layer, but that's not a small job.  What we're really hoping for is that Percona will release one more integrated HS version to work with 5.6, and then that will give us the time we need to examine what's coming down the pipe. For now we're stuck on 5.5.

Comment: To clarify Dimitri's comment a little: The locking he was referring to became hot at very high core-counts (48 cores), while most EC2 instances will have far fewer cores.  Mutexes are common to all DBs trying to control concurrent access.  In the absence of benchmarks, I would not rely on HS automatically being better.

Comment: I agree regarding benchmarks, however HS did have almost a 4 year head start, and its first benchmarks rendered750k+ QPS on *MUCH* smaller commodity hardware (Nehalem 8 cores, E5540 @ 2.53GHz), http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.ca/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html.  I'm interested in where things are going, particularly if the guys at FB are pushing the memcache route, but I'm still not confident that I wouldn't be jumping from one sinking ship to another.  I see a third solution in the future, the only question is do I need a stopgap in memcache, and of that I'm not yet convinced.

Comment: You might be interested to know Yoshinori@Facebook (thanked in Dimitri's post) is the same Yoshinori who wrote the HS post you link to.